# Listing all graph automorphisms from a set of generators (Bliss)?

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, permutation-cycles

## Preface

I'll preface this by saying I asked this question at the Mathematica StackExchange yesterday (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282024/bliss-automorphisms-how-to-list-all-automorphisms-using-the-output-generators) and received a good answer for listing automorphisms using *Mathematica* software.  The software uses a function called "GroupElements" that lists the automorphisms.  However, what I'm basically asking here is how a function like "GroupElements" works under the hood or a general method so I could apply it to any software that outputs generators (Bliss, Nauty, etc.).

## Question

I am using the program called Bliss (http://www.tcs.hut.fi/Software/bliss/index.html) to try to extract all automorphisms of an input graph. The software itself does not list all of the automorphisms directly but instead outputs a list of "generators" that are supposed to be used to list all automorphisms by combining the output of the generators.

What I'm stuck on is that I don't see a clear pattern of how to list ALL automorphisms using the generators. Bliss may output two generators, but the total number of automorphisms could be 4 (which includes the identity mapping).

How would one combine the output of the generators to list ALL autormorphisms?  The generators could come from Bliss or similar software that outputs generators.

## Example 1

[image]

Source: Page 24 [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4203/files/GT-Lec2.pdf](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecs4203/files/GT-Lec2.pdf)

Bliss Output:

```
Graph read in 0.00 seconds
Initial partition computed in 0.00 seconds
Generator: (1,8)(2,7)
Level 1: orbits=6, index=2/2, all_same_level=1
Generator: (3,5)(4,6)
Level 0: orbits=4, index=2/2, all_same_level=0
Nodes:          5
Leaf nodes:     3
Bad nodes:      0
Canrep updates: 1
Generators:     2
Max level:      2
|Aut|:          4
Total time: 0.00 seconds
```

The output says |Aut| = 4, which is correct since there are 4 automorphisms per the example screenshot.

The output has the generators that correspond to two of the automorphisms from the example. Another automorphism is the identity. But what I don't know how to get from these generators is the last automorphism shown in the screenshot using the generators.

## Example 2

As another example from a very similar tool to Bliss called Nauty ([https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/)), Nauty also lists the generators but not all automorphisms as explained in page 3 here [https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/nug26.pdf](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/nug26.pdf) with a good example.  I'll place a screenshot below in case the link becomes dead one day.  Here, there are 8 automorphisms that could be generated by just two generators.
[image]

Thanks, any help is appreciated.